# Is the OpenMP scheduling still efficient with a conditional inner loop?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

Currently, somewhere deep in my code, I am working with a nested for-loop (N1=~10000, N2 = ~500, x,y= 10-50). I used the `#pragma omp`, to have OpenMP distribute my calculation on several cores.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N2; ++j)
    {
        for (int k = x; k <= y; ++k)
        {
            // calculation
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my two innerloops becomes conditional

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
{
    if (toExecute[i])
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N2; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = x; k <= y; ++k)
            {
                // calculation
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The inner nested loop either takes a long time, or is immediately done. Of course I can omit the if-statement by replacing the outer-loop and if-statement with a shorter loop and lookup for the later indexing.

My question is: Is OpenMP smart enough to handle the if-statement within my outer loop, or do I have to do something manually?

I am currently using C++ in Visual Studio 2017 if that matters (I think the OpenMP version is a bit behind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should let OpenMP handle that for you. But as always when you're doing performance stuffs, you have to try to see what is best for you. Indeed, you can gain great speedup by doing things manually. OpenMP is not omniscient, he does not know all the details and intelligence about your calculation.

If your calculation implies the same work of amount for any iteration then your condition is likely to lead to some different work load regarding the most outter loop. So theoritically, a dynamic scheduling should be more fitted
`#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)`

You could also try `static` or `guided` scheduling which might fit your calculation (I don't know the details of your calculation so I cannot say) and play with the granularity block.

An other test to do, if you can afford that (i.e. is it parallelizable ?), you should try to move the parallelization in the inner loops. 
You can even nest the parallelization, it sometimes give nice speedup. Try and tune step by step, take time to see what gives you the best output. Just to remind you these tweaks are often not generic accross different architectures, so aim for a good tradeoff between performance and code reusability.